# "I love you for who you are" vs. "I love you as you are" vs. "I love you for what you are"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, meaning-in-context

> I love you for **who** you are.

I came across the line from a BBC Radio’s drama, and wondered what’s the difference from saying “I love you **as** you are,” or “I love you for **what** you are.” Would you explain the three of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I love you for who you are* = My devotion is inspired by your personality (or, possibly, by your influential family connections).

*I love you as you are* = You’re perfect in my eyes and I don’t want you to change.

*I love you for what you are* = I admire above all your noble and endearing qualities.

Comment: Between monsters the last expression might mean "I admire above all your brutish and nasty qualities."

Answer (score 2):

There is a common expression:

> ***"I love you for what you are, not who you are."***

This always seems to be said to someone who is either famous or powerful in their own right or from an influential family so ***"what you are"*** is about the person's own qualities such as their warm personality, kindness, ability to fill others' needs, etc.

To love someone ***"as you are"*** brings to mind the disclaimer used with discount merchandise - "sold as-is", meaning with all its inherent value and (any) hidden defects.  ;-)